# How to properly implement refresh functionality in WP 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I recently released an App for WP8 about recycling stuff. I'm continuous supporting it with new features and fixing or improving the existing ones.

Basically, what the App does is consume some RSS feeds and display it in the phone. The phone has 4 sections: start, Search, News, Favourites.

The problem I'm having is in the News section. As commented I consume some RSS. When I clicked the refresh button what I did is execute again the same method who is loaded when the App star to show the news. However, I'm getting the same data even if the RSS feed has new ones. Sometimes it takes a while to see the new data.

I'm executing an async method to get the RSS feeds and using the HttpClient. The method looks like this:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<News>> GetNews()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(source);
        var parseResult = XDocument.Parse(result);
        . . .
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //throw
    }
}
```

So, my question is:
What would be the better way to implement the refreshing functionality?

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a caching issue. That is, you are getting a cached response.

Try by appending a meaningless random value to your querystring to avoid getting the cached response. For example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.GetStringAsync(source + "?nocahce=" + Guid.NewGuid());
var parseResult = XDocument.Parse(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

What @anderZubi explained is precise, i was also stuck with this issue for quite a long time  but there is more graceful way for handling this problem 
try adding the DefaultRequestHeaders property to the HttpClient here's the code

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<News>> GetNews()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        var result = await client.GetStringAsync(source);
        var parseResult = XDocument.Parse(result);
        . . .
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //throw
    }
}
```